# Is there a way to get the current playback time using spotify's API

Tags: node.js, api, express, spotify

I am making make a web app where I'll embed my spotify podcast episode. I need certain things to happen on my website once a certain number of seconds have been played. Is there a way to get the playback time using the API?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
/v1/me/player/currently-playing
```

which returns `progress_ms`

---

Example:

**Request**

```
curl -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing" -H "Authorization: Bearer {your access token}"
```

**Response**

```
{
  "context": {
    "external_urls" : {
      "spotify" : "http://open.spotify.com/user/spotify/playlist/49znshcYJROspEqBoHg3Sv"
    },
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/spotify/playlists/49znshcYJROspEqBoHg3Sv",
    "type" : "playlist",
    "uri" : "spotify:user:spotify:playlist:49znshcYJROspEqBoHg3Sv"
  },
  "timestamp": 1490252122574,
  "progress_ms": 44272, <------
  ...
```

---

Also take into consideration that this API is in Beta and may be subject to change without notice. (or have functional or performance issues)

API Documentation is [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/) and [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/get-the-users-currently-playing-track/).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any podcast tool with an API that's not still in beta? Something with this feature.

Comment: Not particularly, but beta doesn't necessarily mean bad quality and changing specs. Especially for a big company as Spotify, I would personally use it for non-critical projects (for example I wouldn't use a beta API for a fintech app, but podcasts should be fine)